# Latex merges dashes

Tags: typography, ligatures

I have the Latex code

```
\textendash \textendash
```

Latex outputs a merged dash

[image]

Instead I want two separate dashes

[image]

How can I type two separate dashes?

Comment: this is just the usual issue that spaces after command names are ignored, you need `\foo{} \foo` or `\foo\ \foo` or `\foo\hspace{3cm}\foo` depending on which output you need

Comment: As @DavidCarlisle says `\textendash{} \textendash` or `\textendash\ \textendash` is what you need, but if you're able to use the traditional TeX ligatures `-- --` that'll also work

Comment: This works. I saw that it is crucial to put space after {}.

Comment: @Viesturs yes just like the `aa` is different from `a a` the output space is the input space.